# What could be causing install errors with pip, conda and setup.py install

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pip, conda

Whenever I try to install a package with pip or pip3 I get an error that starts with:

```
DEPRECATION: Configuring installation scheme with distutils config files is deprecated and will no longer work in the near future. If you are using a Homebrew or Linuxbrew Python, please see discussion at https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/76621
```

and ends with:

```
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      error in decorator setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

using Conda I get the error:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/user1/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-38-darwin.so, 0x0002): Library not loaded: @rpath/libffi.7.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/user1/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-38-darwin.so
  Reason: tried: '/Users/user1/miniconda3/lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/user1/miniconda3/lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/user1/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/../../libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/user1/miniconda3/lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/user1/miniconda3/lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/user1/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/../../libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/user1/miniconda3/lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/user1/miniconda3/bin/../lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/user1/miniconda3/lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/user1/miniconda3/bin/../lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user1/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1212, in print_unexpected_error_report
    message_builder.append(get_main_info_str(error_report['conda_info']))
  File "/Users/user1/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/cli/main_info.py", line 237, in get_main_info_str
    info_dict['_' + key] = ('\n' + 26 * ' ').join(info_dict[key])
KeyError: 'pkgs_dirs'

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/user1/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1080, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/user1/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 84, in _main
        exit_code = do_call(args, p)
      File "/Users/user1/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 83, in do_call
        return getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
      File "/Users/user1/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/cli/main_install.py", line 20, in execute
        install(args, parser, 'install')
      File "/Users/user1/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 259, in install
        unlink_link_transaction = solver.solve_for_transaction(
      File "/Users/user1/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 114, in solve_for_transaction
        unlink_precs, link_precs = self.solve_for_diff(update_modifier, deps_modifier,
      File "/Users/user1/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 157, in solve_for_diff
        final_precs = self.solve_final_state(update_modifier, deps_modifier, prune, ignore_pinned,
      File "/Users/user1/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 262, in solve_final_state
        ssc = self._collect_all_metadata(ssc)
      File "/Users/user1/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/common/io.py", line 88, in decorated
        return f(*args, **kwds)
      File "/Users/user1/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 397, in _collect_all_metadata
        _supplement_index_with_system(virtual_pkg_index)
      File "/Users/user1/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 159, in _supplement_index_with_system
        cuda_version = context.cuda_version
      File "/Users/user1/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/auxlib/decorators.py", line 268, in new_fget
        cache[inner_attname] = func(self)
      File "/Users/user1/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/common/decorators.py", line 20, in wrapper
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/user1/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/base/context.py", line 850, in cuda_version
        return cuda_detect()
      File "/Users/user1/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/common/cuda.py", line 37, in cuda_detect
        import ctypes
      File "/Users/user1/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
        from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
    ImportError: dlopen(/Users/user1/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-38-darwin.so, 0x0002): Library not loaded: @rpath/libffi.7.dylib
      Referenced from: /Users/user1/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-38-darwin.so
      Reason: tried: '/Users/user1/miniconda3/lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/user1/miniconda3/lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/user1/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/../../libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/user1/miniconda3/lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/user1/miniconda3/lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/user1/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/../../libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/user1/miniconda3/lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/user1/miniconda3/bin/../lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/user1/miniconda3/lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/user1/miniconda3/bin/../lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file)
```

Are these errors related? What could be causing this type of error.  If I install from source (setup.py) the module will install but I'll get an error about a circular import. I've tried installing with sudo, for example using:

```
sudo -H pip install bat-country
```

but that doesn't work. If I activate a conda environment I can install with pip within it but I also get the circular import error. conda install does not work from within an environment. Is there anyway to debug this?

Comment: I've hit this dylib issue before, but can't remember how I have solved it. Try renaming one of the dylib to have a .so extension as described here: https://github.com/MoDeNa-EUProject/MoDeNa/issues/1

I'm not making this an 'Answer' because I don't _know_ how to solve it, but I hope this research helps.

Comment: Lib issues almost always have to do with mixing `conda-forge` with the `defaults` channel. I advise against using sudo with Conda - that's only going to complicate matters further. Really hard to give Conda-specific advice without including `conda list` output in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may have been an apple silicon issue. I was able to fix the particular error by doing a search for libffi.7.dylib and adding the enclosing folder to package directories using "conda config --file < path to .condarc > --add pkgs_dirs < path to libffi.7.dylib enclosing folder >" or also by coping the contents of the enclosing folder to one of the directories conda said it searched in the error message. This, however, did not fix the numerous other install and import errors I was having. The solution was to download MiniForge from here: (https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge)and running

`chmod +x ~/Downloads/Miniforge3-MacOSX-arm64.sh`

`sh ~/Downloads/Miniforge3-MacOSX-arm64.sh`

`source ~/miniforge3/bin/activate`